# delete s3 object using pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

i need delete object

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def delete_object(bucket_name, object_name):
    # Delete the object
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

a = delete_object("dgaray-bucket","consolidado.dat")
```

generates error

Command failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you simply try doing this first to see if you are able to delete the object, assuming that the credentials are all set in place.
`import boto3`
`client = boto3.client('s3')`
`client.delete_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key='file')`

also its better to give a different name to the python method rather than using the same as that of the boto3 method name delete_object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

def delete_object(bucket_name, object_name):
 # Delete the object
 s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)

a = delete_object("name-bucket","directory/file.dat")
```

I failed because of the spark session.